# Why is phantomJS unable to get markup from this page?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I've tried this code on some sites and it works but on others it seems PhantomJS and casperJS aren't able to wait for dynamically loaded content successfully. The content loaded by JavaScript isn't visible to casperJS even after waiting for a couple of minutes.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false
  }
});


casper.start('https://betyetu.co.ke/sportsbook/SOCCER/');

casper.waitFor(function check() {
  return this.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('div.events-app__group').length > 1;
  });
}, function then() {
  this.echo('Found elements');
  }, function timeout() {
    this.echo('Still timing out before returning element count');
  }, 60000);

casper.run();
```

When I query for only a div without the class, it returns the message that matching elements have been found. This is from the outer scaffolding that doesn't require JS for loading. All the inner elements with the data I'm interested in don't get loaded / aren't available to casperJS. Why is this the case?

Comment: First of all, are you sure you don't hav mispelled your class ? (it seems to contain 2 underscores) And are you sure there's at least 1 `div` with the desired class in the content ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I've copied it from the site itself which can be found here: https://betyetu.co.ke/sportsbook/SOCCER/ To select it, once the page is loaded on your browser, click on the section labelled 'up coming matches' and you'll find a list of divs under the div.js-child-container that match the query

Comment: i noticed that the class `events-app__group` is added later by js. you will need to wait until the js ran and fetched the content.

Comment: @BagusTesa How can I do this wait? I thought that this is taken care of by increasing the timeout to 1 minute; I've tried to wait for up to 4 minutes to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is a helper library for running PhantomJS scripts. PhantomJS has quite outdated web engine that doesn't support modern javascript, so sites will break more and more often in PhantomJS. The target site is one of those that won't work fully in PhantomJS or even Internet Explorer 11.

But using *polyfills*, libraries that emulate newer js features for older browsers, we can use CasperJS for a little bit longer. Here I *inject* the excellent [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/v2) library right after creating a page in PhantomJS, but before going to the site. This way our old browser will possess a new set of javascript features.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    // it's better to blend with the crowd
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
        loadImages: false
    },
    viewportSize : { width: 1280, height: 720 },
    verbose: true,
});

// Apply the bandaid in the form of core.js polyfill
casper.on('page.initialized', function() {
    casper.page.injectJs('./core.js');
});

casper.start('https://betyetu.co.ke/sportsbook/SOCCER/');

casper.waitFor(function check() {
  return this.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('div.events-app__group').length > 1;
  });
}, function then() {
  var count = this.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('div.events-app__group').length;
  });
  this.echo('Found elements: ' + count);
  casper.capture('screen.jpg');
}, function timeout() {
    this.echo('Still timing out before returning element count');
}, 5000);

casper.run();
```

> Found elements: 28

Comment: Thanks for coming to my aid again bro. Truly grateful. The solution works elegantly. Bounty's yours in a couple of hours. As per your answer, it would appear that one might want to move away from phantom to a more modern headless set up; what are you currently using or what do you recommend based on your experience coming from the phantom world?

Comment: Glad it worked! As for a more modern stack -
 nowadays it's definitely [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to migrate to. It uses the freshest Chromium (or your preinstalled Chrome) and is being actively developed by Google.

Comment: Since this worked could you please mark the answer as *the* solution?

Comment: Done. I thought I had done it already. Thanks for pointing me to puppeteer for my next project as well.